# Rescaling images in mnist

Tags: python, image-processing, deep-learning, mnist

So I am trying to load the data and rescale the images values and return the rescaled train and test sets.
Here is what I am trying:

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0/255.0)
```

It is incomplete and I don't know how to proceed after this

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flow` method in `ImageDataGenerator` ([check more on documentation](https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/)) as follows:

It expects the input dimension to be `reshaped` with 4 dimension. Since mnist dataset have `60000` images and `28*28` height and width with a single channel. The reshaped size would be `(60000, 1, 28, 28)`

```
training_set = datagen.flow(train_images.reshape(train_images.shape[0], 1, 28, 28), train_labels)

test_set = datagen.flow(test_images.reshape(test_images.shape[0], 1, 28, 28), test_labels)
```

You should define your model architecture as you needed then use `fit_generator` function.

### Train your model

```
classifier.fit_generator(training_set, 
                         steps_per_epoch=10, 
                         validation_data= test_set, 
                         validation_steps=20, 
                         epochs=5)
```

Comment: More on this on the documentation page https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/. Best

Comment: How am I supposed to retreive the rescaled train and test sets from after this

Comment: You can iterate the `training_set` using for loop to get the respective data as list